# Windows 11 wireless connection disconnects after return from hibernation

Tags: windows, windows-11-v22h2

I have an hp laptop that I upgraded to win 11 from win 10.
Almost every time my computer powers up after hibernation my wifi stays disconnected and only restores after full shut down and power up. Restart doesn't help.

Things I have tried: from this website

https://woshub.com/group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-for-windows-10-home/

1. Disabled the option to let windows turn off this device to save power.
2. Disabled and enabled wifi adapter
3. Tried to update driver. No update was possible because it is already updated.
4. Restarted wlan autoconfig
5. Restarted wifi adapter using power shell. I could not restart it because the command couldn't recognize the adapter name.
6. Couldn't ipen gpedit ormstd.exe because the computer did not recognize the software.

Comment: What is the network adapter ?

Comment: Hibernation requires proper and compliant drivers.   Update BIOS (UEFI) (do take care you have the correct BIOS update); update Power Drivers;  Update the Wireless Card drivers.

Comment: I've tried updating. Do you maybe have other ideas?